# Element with id 'checkvalues' not found (anonymous) @ check_codes.php:580

Tags: php, html

When a user double clicks a row of data on the checkcodes card, the user should be presented with additional data shown on the checkvalues card, currently the checkcodes card content disapears and the checkvalues card remains blank, looking at the dev tools on google chrome im getting the following errors but cant identify the solution - Element with id 'checkvalues' not found
(anonymous) @ check_codes.php:580
Failed to parse response as JSON TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'querySelector')
at populateCheckValuesTable (check_codes.php:615:59)
at xhr.onreadystatechange (check_codes.php:602:6)

this is my HTML code

```
                <!-- Content area -->
                <div class="content">
                <div class="tab-content flex-1 order-1 order-lg-1">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="checkcodes">
                    <!-- Individual column searching (selects) Check Codes -->
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">Check Codes</h5>
                        <div class="card-body d-flex justify-content-between">
                        </div>
                        <table class="table datatable-fixed-left table-hover table-xs" id="checkcodes-table">
                            <?php include('assets/php/check_code.php'); ?>
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <?php foreach ($table_data as $checkcode) { ?>
                                <tr class="check-code" data-checkcode="<?php echo $checkcode['code_name']; ?>">
                                <td><?php echo $checkcode['code_name']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $checkcode['code_description']; ?></td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /individual column searching (selects) check codes -->
                </div>
                <?php
                // Check if the "checkcode" parameter is present in the URL
                if (isset($_GET['checkcode'])): ?>
                    <div class="tab-pane hidden" id="checkvalues">
                        <!-- Individual column searching (selects) Check Values -->
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <?php include('assets/php/check_value.php'); ?>
                                <h5 class="mb-0">Check Values - 
                                    <span id="checkvalues-checkname">
                                        <?php echo htmlspecialchars($checkvalue['check_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
                                    </span>
                                </h5>
                            </div>
                            <table class="table datatable-fixed-left table-hover table-xs" id="checkvalues-table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Id</th>
                                        <th>Text</th>
                                        <th>Mnemonic</th>
                                        <th>Image</th>
                                        <th>Definition</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <?php foreach ($table_data as $checkvalue): ?>
                                        <tr class="check-value" data-checkvalue="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($checkvalue['check_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>">
                                            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($checkvalue['check_id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($checkvalue['check_text'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($checkvalue['check_mnemonic'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($checkvalue['check_image'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($checkvalue['check_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($checkvalue['check_definition'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /individual column searching (selects) check values -->
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
                <!-- /content area -->
          
                <!-- Footer -->
                <?php include 'assets/php/front_end_segments/footer.php'; ?>
                <!-- /footer -->

            </div>
            <!-- /inner content -->

        </div>
        <!-- /main content -->

    </div>
    <!-- /page content -->
    <script>
      window.addEventListener("unload", function() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "assets/php/logout.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
      });
    </script>
    <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        console.log('DOMContentLoaded');
        var checkCodeRows = document.querySelectorAll(".check-code");

        checkCodeRows.forEach(function (row) {
            row.addEventListener("dblclick", function () {
                console.log('Row double clicked', row);
                var checkCodeName = row.getAttribute("data-checkcode");
                console.log('checkCodeName', checkCodeName);

                document.getElementById("checkcodes").classList.remove("active", "show");
                var checkValuesTab = document.getElementById("checkvalues");
                if (checkValuesTab) {
                    checkValuesTab.classList.add("active", "show");
                    checkValuesTab.classList.remove("hidden");
                } else {
                    console.error("Element with id 'checkvalues' not found");
                }


                console.log('Attempting to load check values');
                loadCheckValues(checkCodeName);
            });
        });
    });

    function loadCheckValues(checkCodeName) {
        console.log('loadCheckValues', checkCodeName);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "assets/php/check_value.php?checkcode=" + checkCodeName, true);

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            console.log('xhr.onreadystatechange - readyState, status', xhr.readyState, xhr.status);
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                console.log('Response received', xhr.responseText);
                try {
                    var checkValues = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    console.log('Parsed check values', checkValues);
                    populateCheckValuesTable(checkValues);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.error("Failed to parse response as JSON", e);
                }
            } else if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                console.error("Request failed", xhr.status, xhr.statusText);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    }

    function populateCheckValuesTable(checkValues) {
        console.log('populateCheckValuesTable', checkValues);
        var tbody = document.getElementById("checkvalues-table").querySelector("tbody");
        tbody.innerHTML = "";
        
        checkValues.forEach(function (checkValue) {
            console.log('Appending check value', checkValue);
            var row = document.createElement("tr");
            
            ["check_id", "check_text", "check_mnemonic", "check_image", "check_definition"].forEach(function (key) {
                var cell = document.createElement("td");
                cell.textContent = checkValue[key];
                row.appendChild(cell);
            });
            
            tbody.appendChild(row);
        });
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

and this is my PHP code that retirives the data from the server for the double clicked row

```
<?php

require 'credentials/credentials.php';

$mysqli = new mysqli($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

// Handle potential connection error
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    exit();
}

// Check for the 'checkcode' parameter and handle if not provided
if (!isset($_GET['checkcode'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request');
    echo "Error: No check code provided";
    exit();
}

$selectedCheckCode = $_GET['checkcode'];

// Use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection
$query = "SELECT * FROM check_value WHERE check_name = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

// Handle potential prepare() error
if (!$stmt) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    echo "Error preparing statement: " . $mysqli->error;
    exit();
}

// Bind parameter, execute statement, and bind result
$stmt->bind_param('s', $selectedCheckCode);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

// Fetch data
$table_data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// Close the statement and connection
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();

// Return the data as JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($table_data);

?>
```